# Finding area of quartic

Tags: calculus, geometry, area

Suppose we have a shape $x^4 + y^4 = R^4$. How can we find the area of this?

> My initial thought was to find $\int_0^R\sqrt[4]{R^4 - X^4}dx$ and multiply this by 4, but I am struggling to find the antiderivative. Is there a better approach?

Comment: Green's Theorem might work.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/138169/1181491)