# Is it possible to calculate the area of a squircle by hand?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function

I got this question in an online assessment where you weren't allowed to use a programming language or online resources.

The question defines a squircle by $y^4 + x^4 = R^4$. It's area would be $4\int^R_0 (R^4-x^4)^\frac{1}{4}dx$.

I know the answer uses Gamma functions, so how could you even be expected to work this out? What about if you assume you have a means of calculating Gamma functions, how would you get to this point?

Comment: If you cannot use online resources, what are you doing here? :-)

Comment: The test is over and I'm curious!

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): edit your post to show your work. Hint: no need of Gamma to obtain the result you quote. Just do like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44631).

Comment: But I don't understand whether you are asking for a proof of that formula for the area, or how to [transform it into some other formula involving Gamma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138169/integration-area-enclosed-by-graph-of-x4-y4-1?noredirect=1), or what else. What were the question and the answer of the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can compute the special case $R = 1$ without loss of generality and then multiply the result by $R^2$ to get the general case.

This means we want to compute

$$I = \int_{x=0}^1 (1-x^4)^{1/4} \, dx.$$

The choice $$t = x^4, \quad x = t^{1/4}, \quad dx = \frac{1}{4} t^{-3/4} \, dt,$$ yields
$$I = \frac{1}{4} \int_{t=0}^1 (1-t)^{1/4} t^{-3/4} \, dt.$$
Then using the beta function identity
$$B(a,b) = \int_{t=0}^1 t^{a-1} (1-t)^{b-1} \, dt = \frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)},$$
we obtain
$$I = \frac{1}{4} \frac{\Gamma(1/4)\Gamma(5/4)}{\Gamma(3/2)} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \Gamma(5/4)^2.$$

So the general area will be
$$4R^2 I = \frac{8}{\sqrt{\pi}} \Gamma(5/4)^2 R^2.$$  The value of $\Gamma(5/4)$ has no further simplification.

As an exercise, what is the enclosed area for the family of such curves given by $$x^{2n} + y^{2n} = 1$$ for positive integers $n$?